# Blaze Advisor 6.8 Error when deploying project to WebMethods Integration Server

Tags: business-rules, webmethods

I'm using Blaze Advisor 6.8 to develop a project for work. I've been struggling with the error on the image below. Basically, it won't let me deploy my project onto webMethods Integration Server.

[image]

I've checked the directory mentioned in the error message. It's clean. I've also deleted that same directory, restarted webMethods Servers, restarted the machine where those server are installed. I've checked the database where the code repository is located for any deadlocks, and it's also clean. I've also tried to rebuild the repository or make a new one. Same error happens, but only for this project.

Anyone has seen this before? Can you provide a solution or a workaround?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with Blaze and webMethods.

So, this is just a shot in the dark.

Does Blaze create instances of itself in webMethods Integration Server? You might need to destroy or disable those instances in order to be able to overwrite it. Or maybe disable the entire blaze webMethods adapter/add-on. Are there any such options from the webMethods administration web console ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried disabling the addon on webMethods. While disabling it does make Blaze to present a different message upon deployment, re-enabling it brings back the message on the picture, unfortunately.
Maybe reinstalling the whole Blaze Advisor IDE might solve the issue... If I try to deploy a project with the same name but on other repositories, the same error occurs. I'm starting to think it is and IDE issue.

Thanks again for your help!